# Dynamic shards in Dataflow with Template approach

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, sharding

I have a pipeline to extract data from BigQuery and write data to file using Apache Beam. Here Iam using a template approach for Dataflow. All good if I hard code the number of shards at compile time during template creation. But my requirement to decide the number of shards at runtime based on the number of rows extracting from BigQuery. Example if there are more than 1million records then write to another file. Is this achievable in Dataflow while using a template approach. I know this works fine if we use a non template approach where all the parameters are passed at runtime.**I am explicitly looking for template approach.**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ValueProvider](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-pipeline-options) when you write your template.

> Use `ValueProvider` for all pipeline options that you want to set or use at runtime.

Then you can use the parameter value in your logic to determine the number of shards.

Answer (score 0):

While writing record to a file we can call a PTransform which can decide on the number of shared used based on the number of records in the upstream Pcollection.

```
FileIO.write().withSharding(new calculateNumOfShards()).via(TextIO.sink())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [Flex Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) which have the full flexibility of non-template pipelines.